# Visual studio 2010: how to watch a memory hex location

Tags: visual-studio

I tried some suggestions found online but it does not work for me. Im using Visual Studio 2010. Basically I typed loc(kcs(1,4)) (thats my variable) and I obtained 157510036. Its hex is 9636994. So then I typed (INTEGER*)0x9636994 but on the watch window under the "value"column it says "undefined variable INTEGER". I trid lowercase integer or real and same answer.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> I typed (INTEGER*)0x9636994 but on the watch window under the "value"column it says "undefined variable INTEGER".

According to [Restrictions on Native C++ Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0888kc6a(v=vs.100).aspx):

> ## Type Casting
>
> If you cast to a type, the type must be known to the debugger. You must have another object of that type in your program. **Types created using typedef statements are not supported**.

Try using the underlying type. So, for example, if `INTEGER` is actually an `int` you would try to watch `(int *)0x9636994`.

This also assumes that the variable is fixed at `0x9636994` (basically that you're not trying to refer to something transient on the stack).

Comment: The variable is an allocatable variable in a fortran module and it is at a fixed memory location. Loc gives always the same value throughout the program. I tried (int *)0x9636994 as suggested but it gives "syntax error "under the "value"column. Any other idea?

Comment: @Alberto You could try `*(int *)0x9636994`. But beyond that, the only other thing I could think of is the constraint that *(if) you cast to a type, the type must be known to the debugger.* But having no `int`s in your application seems unlikely.

Comment: Any update on this? I did not figure it out yet....both *(int *) or (int *) do not work